# Android phone does not receive push notification when app is killed

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Android phone does not receive push notification when app is killed.
I'm using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification

Push notification comes when app is in foreground and background. How can I make phone receive push notification when app is killed.
Below is my API code

```
$fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $notification = [
        'title' => $title,
        "body" =>$body,
        "myId"=>$id,
        "orderId"=>$order_id,
        "sound"=> "rush",
        "ledColor"=> [0,0,255,0],
    ];
    
    $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification];

    $fcmNotification = [
        'to'        => $token, //single token
        'notification' => $notification,
        'data' => $extraNotificationData
    ];
    $headers = [
        'Authorization: key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Still battling with this. Can anyone help